# Ubuntu asks me for a serial number when trying to install?

Tags: system-installation

I am attempting to install Ubuntu, and I am getting a serial number prompt.

I don't understand, if Ubuntu is free, why do I need to enter a serial number?  How do I obtain one?

[image]

Comment: I never encountered this before. Ubuntu **is** free. How did you install? Where did you get your installation medium from?

Comment: Have you downloaded the install-media from Ubuntu website ot where ?

Comment: Is it a genuine site? What is the link please?

Comment: [@Richard](https://askubuntu.com/users/898540/richard) please do tell us about the source of the installation medium.

Comment: That looks like a window running in macOS. Ubuntu has no installer executable anymore, and when it did, it was only for Windows. You aren't using an official installer.

Comment: You're using an invalid, malicious installer.  DO NOT continue to use it.  Ubuntu is free and has ***NO*** serial codes.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, I have never seen such before. Ubuntu Operating System is 100% free.

I think this installer you're using is probably not Ubuntu OS or at least is a customized version made by someone else.

To cut the long story short, I will recommend you download Ubuntu form [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and install.